# Can't find groovy-starter.conf

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I'm building a grails app that links to a mongodb database and it's the first time I've used either, it was all going well unitl I dropped the database (I had done this many times before and had no problem) and then when I tried to run the app again it came up with this error...

Exception while configuring main class loader:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\TC5JXQ28\springsource\grails-2.0.3\conf\groovy-starter.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
```

I followed the path and it only gets about halfway through before it breaks. Could anyone help me understand what this means and how to point it back to the right place?

Comment: Have you installed Grails or STS inside your temporary internet files folder? If so, I'm guessing you cleared your browser cache, and it removed it...

Comment: Thanks Tim! I completely reinstalled STS but this time installed it in a proper file location and it seems to be working fine, thanks for the advice.